# MYSQL status variables in red, how to interpret them

Tags: mysql

```
Aborted_connects         | 4
Created_tmp_disk_tables  | 64
Handler_read_rnd         | 2.2 k
Handler_read_rnd_next    | 149.8 k
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads | 1.1 k    
Key_reads                | 242
Opened_tables            | 198
Qcache_free_blocks       | 1
Slow_queries             | 14
Sort_merge_passes        | 1
```

these values are in red, and some are increasing every minute very fast
In particular Handler_read_rnd and Handler_read_rnd_next seem to increase very rapidly..

(all the other variables are green or neutral)

is there  a way to know which query is affecting these values?
how do I decrease them?

Ps. I enabled slow-query-log and log-queries-not-using-indexes

Comment: May we know what exactly you are running on MySQL which generates these numbers?

Comment: what do you mean? I'm running a php ecommerce